# Can we set Two LoginManger() instance in __init__.py

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am beginner to Flask Framework

I need to know that if I have multiple kind of users eg, student and teacher and I'm doing it all in same models.py file so do I have to set 2 LoginManager() instance in the init.py like student_login_manager=LoginManager() also teacher_login_manger?

```
student_login_manager.init_app(app)
student_login_manager.login_view('login_student')

teacher_login_manager.init_app(app)
teacher_login_manager.login_view('login_teacher')
```

if not then is there any another way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use a single `login_manager` object in your factory function, but update the `login_view`s to individual users:

```py
login_manager.init_app(app)

# View function handling the login logic for student
login_manager.login_view = 'login_student' 

# View function handling the login logic for teacher
login_manager.login_view = 'login_teacher'
```